# Testing 'throw' with mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

In my function I use:

```
  if (apples === undefined) {
    throw new Error('Error');
  }
```

In my test I am trying to confirm this is working by doing:

```
  it('throw an error if apples is undefined', function() {
    const input = undefined;
    const output = "Error";
    assert.throws(myFunc(input), output);
  });
```

However I get:

1 failing

1. myFunc
   should throw an error if apples is undefined:
   Error
   Error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node assert.throws not catching exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645559/node-assert-throws-not-catching-exception)

Answer (score 0):

That's because [`assert.throws`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_fn_error_message) 1st parameter takes the function *definition*, not the function *result*. It calls the passed function itself. In your example, you're calling the function therefore you're passing the function result.

Instead of this:

```
assert.throws(myFunc(), output)
```

Do it like this:

```
assert.throws(myFunc, output)
```

If you want to pass parameters to the function under test, you'll need to wrap it in another unnamed function or use [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind some arguments to it.

Here's a working example:

```
const assert = require("assert")

function myFunc(apples) {
  if (!apples) {
    throw new Error("Apples must have a non-null value");
  }

  return apples + " are good";
}


describe("myFunc", () => {
  it("throws an error if apples is undefined", function() {
    const input = undefined;
    const output = new Error("Error");

    assert.throws(function() {
      myFunc(input);
    }, output);
  })
})
```

Note that you also need to test that it throws an instance of an `Error` instead of a `String`.